# rails 3.2 custom error pages 404, 422, 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

Rails serves error 404, 422, 500 errors from `public/{404,422,500}.html` files

what is the way to serve those errors more dynamically?

p.s `rescue_from` and `rescue_action_in_public` doesn't seem to work in rails 3.2.11